# Can I create file in server using CURL?

Tags: windows, curl, http

I have a windows machine, where I have shared a location and made it open through browser using https. Something like this- "https://my-windows/test".

I am writing a shell script which will post a file to this machine/url. I am able to download file using curl from this location but when I post/put, it gives me error. It says that I am trying to put it in a folder and expected is a file.

I don't want to over write an existing file. I want to create a new file. Is this possible with curl? I am writing this shell script in Linux box and destination is a windows box.

I tried following:

```
1. curl -D- -u user:pass -X POST --data "@test.txt" https://my-windows/test

HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established

HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed


2. curl -D- -u user:pass -X PUT --data "@test.txt" https://my-windows/test

{
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 500,
    "message" : "Expected a file but found a folder
       }
   ]}


3. curl -D- -u user:pass -F "file=@test.txt;filename=nameinpost" https://my-windows/test

HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established

HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Allow: GET,PUT,DELETE
Content-Length: 0
```

Comment: what does this do? `curl -D- -u user:pass -X PUT --data "@test.txt" https://my-windows/test/test.txt`

Comment: I am passing my credentials(username and password) and telling that I am using PUT.

Comment: I mean including the file name in the path. `https://my-windows/test/test.txt` instead of `https://my-windows/test`.

Comment: OhI Sorry, did not read completely. https://my-windows/test/test.txt instead of https://my-windows/test works. It created test.txt. Thank you sooo much! I was so stuck with this. Thanks a ton!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error in the second message suggests that you need to include the file name, like this:

```
curl -D- -u user:pass -X PUT --data "@test.txt" https://my-windows/test/test.txt
```